# Invalid repository type PYTHON. Valid type is PYPI

Tags: google-artifact-registry

I have created (using terraform resource [google_artifact_registry_repository](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/artifact_registry_repository)) a python repository on [Google Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/overview). Here's my terraform code that created it:

```
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "pypi" {
  provider      = google-beta
  project       = var.project_id
  location      = var.region
  repository_id = "dataplatformpypi"
  description   = "PyPi repo for use by dataplatform"
  format        = "PYTHON"
}
```

here is that repository:

[image]

I am now following the quickstart at https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/quickstart, specifically the [Configure authentication](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/quickstart#configure) section which instructs me to issue `gcloud artifacts print-settings python`. I actually modify that slightly to issue:

```sh
gcloud --project myproject artifacts print-settings python --repository dataplatformpypi --location europe-west2
```

and I get error:

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.print-settings.python) Invalid repository type PYTHON. Valid type is PYPI.
```

I haven't specified the repository type as part of that command so I can only assume that "repository type PYTHON" refers to the format of the repository:

[image]

However given that the repository has been created successfully and PYTHON is (according to the [terraform resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/artifact_registry_repository#format)) a valid value for the repository format I am struggling to understand what the problem is here.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What happens when you change format to PYPI?

Comment: Hi. its not possible to change it. Instead I tried to create a new repository via the console and Python was one of the options (alongside Docker, NPM etc), PyPi was not an option.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear to be a user-specific problem. Other users have also encountered the issue. There's a similar issue ongoing in GitHub. You can follow the thread [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-python-tools/issues/19).

Comment: Thank you Mabel, I've left a comment on that thread.